# top/bottomMargin with fillHeight components

Tags: qt, qml

I'm facing a problem regarding top / bottom margin on components inside a layout (GridLayout here, but it seems to be the same with a ColumnLayout) with fillHeight.

Considering the following example:

`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Item {
    width : 800
    height : 480
    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2
        rows : 2
        Rectangle {
            color:"red"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            width : 400
        }
        Rectangle {
            color:"green"
            Layout.rowSpan: 2
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            width : 400
        }
        Rectangle {
            color:"blue"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            width : 400
            Layout.bottomMargin: 10
        }
    }
}
```

`
The display is as [image: WithBottom.jpg].

Just commenting the line "Layout.bottomMargin: 10" restablish the ratio between red and blue rectangles:

[image: WithoutBottom.jpg]

There seem to be a ratio calculated that take into account the margins when my guess is that it shouldn't. Indeed, the height of the blue rectangle seems to be (top+bottom margins)*height of the red one (I've tested with like a dozen values, maybe not enough).

Answer (score 1):

The layout engine indeed uses the `implicitHeight` to calculate the resulting sizes. Since the `implicitHeight` of a Rectangle is 0, the blue rectangle will be 10 times as big as the red. You can play a bit with setting `implicitHeight` on the rectangles:

```
Item {
    width : 800
    height : 480
    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2
        rows : 2
        Rectangle {
            color:"red"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            implicitHeight: 200
            width : 400
            onHeightChanged: console.log("red", height)
        }
        Rectangle {
            color:"green"
            Layout.rowSpan: 2
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            width : 400
        }
        Rectangle {
            color:"blue"
            implicitHeight: 200
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            width : 400
            Layout.bottomMargin: 10
            onHeightChanged: console.log("blue", height)
        }
    }
}
```

However, this feels like a dirty solution. The resulting size depends on the `implicitHeight` set, but not completely. Basically you alter how much the "weight" of the bottomMargin is in the calculation of the layout engine.

To make a non-dirty solution, you can put the blue Rectangle inside a Item and anchors the blue Rectangle to it with a bottom margin. (so, no Layout.bottomMargin in the Item). But this depends a bit on your desired end-result, as the blue rectangle will be smaller than the red one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply !

Yeah, to me, it is definitely a dirty solution to put an implicitHeight and I can't really apply it to my app.

The other solution is almost like the one I thought about. The difference is that I put a ColumnLayout that fills its parent (with a rowSpan: 2) and contains both the red and blue Rectangles and in which I ask for a Layout.bottomPadding. And this way it works.

This is just a workaround that work for what I want to do, but with this, there's no way to have a topMargin on the blue rectangle without using a spacing. But as I said, this is fine for me.

> as the blue rectangle will be smaller than the red one

Yes, I'm aware of that, and it is what I expect. And with my solution there's also this difference of height.

Edit : no, I'm completely mistaken for that last point and in fact, with the ColumnLayout, red and blue will be the same size : [with a layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI2BE.png)